# UIImagePickerController: [PLImageScrollView release]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, uiimagepickercontroller, ios6

I am writing an iOS6 app using Cocos2D with ARC turned on (Cocos is linked as a static library, not under ARC). I am able to present the camera using the following code:

```
cameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
// set other properties of camera
cameraController.delegate = psImageLayer;
psImageLayer.imagePicker = cameraController;
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:cameraController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and I dismiss the camera in `psImageLayer` with this code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {
    // do something with image
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I dismiss the camera, the app crashes with the following error: `*** -[PLImageScrollView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2494f4f0` I am pretty sure that `PLImageScrollView` is an iOS class, because I did not write it.

My issue appears to be very similar to the issue posted [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/312282-release-sent-to-deallocated-instance-under-arc-how.html), but his solution involves modifying the class that owns the delegate. In this case, UIImagePickerController is the class, which cannot be modified.

The relevant parts of the PhotoShareImageLayer header file are posted below:

```
// PhotoShareImageLayer.h (this is what psImageLayer is)
@interface PhotoShareImageLayer : CCLayer <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *currentImage;

@end
```

Any ideas on how to stop this error from happening? Thanks.

EDIT: List of things I have already tried.

- Subclassing UIImagePickerController and adding `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
      [self setDelegate:nil];
  }`

EDIT 2: The crash does not happen in `imagePickerController:didCancel`. Only when a picture is taken, OR when "Retake" is pressed in the camera. There is no UIImagePickerDelegate method for "Retake" (only "Cancel" and "Use").

EDIT 3: After continuing and writing more of the app, it appears this issue is not unique to the camera. The same (or very similar) errors occur when dismissing modal views for Twitter, Facebook, Contacts, and more.

Comment: Tip: try it in a blank app, and without cocos2d, to make sure it works in principle. If that works, try the same in a blank cocos2d app. That way you at least know where the problem comes from. If both tests succeed, it's something about your project. If the cocos2d test fails, you know it's cocos2d messing things up.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks for the tips. I made both blank apps, and it worked fine, so there must be something wrong with my app.

Comment: @lauren Did you find out what the problem was in your original project ? I'm currently experiencing the same issue in my code. ARC releases the UIImagePickerController correctly in iOS 5.1, in iOS6 it get's over released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a problem with Apple's internal implementation of `PLImageScrollView`. I'm swizzling the UIScrollView`s setDelegate method and this causes a crash when a UIImagePicker is used (although, it only seems to be if you select a photo, not if you cancel). The problem I end up seeing is that the scrollViewDidScroll: method is sent to the real delegate (through my interceptor), but it's already been released.

This suggests to me that the PLImageScrollView's delegate is being dealloced without being nilled out. I half-solved the problem by creating my own `strong` reference to the real delegate. This could cause a memory leak in other implementations, but that's better than a crash at least.